# Cannot set a value to non-existent attribute within a field HTML

Tags: html, forms, screen-scraping, robobrowser

I have this issue. I am trying to fill forms of this website using robobrowser. My code in python is below:

```
new_CRTS_DR3_beta_url = 'http://crts.iucaa.in/CRTS/'
browser = RoboBrowser()
browser.open(new_CRTS_DR3_beta_url)
form = browser.get_form(action='/CRTS/imaging')
form['query_input'].value = '332.64277 -22.66323' 
form['radius'].value = '0.1'
```

However, 'query_input' does not have the attribute value before I fill the input, and when the input is filled the attribute value appears and is set with the input value. The HTML code looks like:

Before when it is empty:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="hidden" id="query_input" 
name="query_input">
```

After setting an input:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="hidden" id="query_input" name="query_input" value="332.64277,-22.66323">
```

Thank you for any help!